# How to iterate through nested lists, printing the value of an index before a searched one

Tags: python, loops, csv, for-loop, iterator

In python: 
Apologies if title is confusing. I have a list of lists obtained from my Kindle's clippings.txt file. I would like to search through the list, only printing the actual words or sentences that I have highlighted. The format for the .csv file is:

```
経済ヤクザ (角川文庫) (一橋 文哉) (BOOK)
- 位置No. 4-4のハイライト |作成日: 2020年3月21日土曜日14:53:17 *(DATE / PAGE)*
(EMPTY LINE)
無断 (WORD THAT I WANT)
========== (SEPARATOR
経済ヤクザ (角川文庫) (一橋 文哉)
- 位置No. 4-4のハイライト |作成日: 2020年3月21日土曜日 14:53:40

転載、
==========
```

And so on. My code so far is:

```
import csv
raw_list = []
path = r'D:\Desktop\kindlewords.txt'
#open file, append each line to raw_list
with open(path, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for line in csv_reader:
        raw_list.append(line)
    csv_file.close()

print(raw_list)
for block in raw_list:
    for characters in block:
        if '===' in characters:
           print(raw_list[raw_list.index(block)-1])
```

My issue is that this returns a ton of ['無断'], which is only the FIRST word that I would want from the lists -- it appears that it only will hit the word right before the first occurrence of '=========='.

I would like to be able to find all occurrences, and am open to any method (I have tried a regex, but don't really know how to use it in this case).

[image: The data I am searching from]

[image: What the current code prints]

First image is of the format of the .txt file, and the second is what is printing by my current code.

Comment: So you want the word, book and pages? Or the first sentence after "=="? Also would help if you paste a  sample of your file (1 or 2 paragraphs)

Comment: @andreis11 I only want the word. There should be an image of the sample there - does it not show up? - EDIT: I suppose it would be considered a sentence too. Just the line before each of the "=======" ' s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a closer look at you code, I spotted the issue and came with a solution:

```
for index, block in enumerate(raw_list):
  for characters in block:
    if '===' in characters:
      print(raw_list[index-1])
```

You were getting the same values because the index of "that value" was the same always.(duplicate value in list)

for example:

```
example_list = [1,2,1]

for x in example_list:
  print(example_list.index(x))
```

You would get:

```
0
1
0
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome! Would appreciate if you mark as answer too!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable to hold the content of the previous line as you iterate through the lines of the input file, and output the previous line if the current line is equal to the record separator:

```
with open(path) as file:
    for line in map(str.rstrip, file):
        if line == '==========':
            print(prev)
        prev = line
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/GlossyPungentGlitch